# Should community wiki answers count towards tag badges?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, badges, community-wiki

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/192808)

> - The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
> - The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.

However, it appears that the upvotes gained before the CW mode was entered do not count towards tag badges (based on [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17564445/819272) that did count 120 towards my rep but not 12 towards the c++ and c++11 tag badges). I understand that post-CW status upvotes are lost, but pre-CW status upvotes should be counting towards everything. I find the current counting rather annoying.

**Question**: why not let pre-CW upvotes count towards tag badges?

Comment: I guess next time you'll make fewer, larger, edits! Were you aware of the auto wiki behavior before this?

Comment: @MartinSmith no this was a surprise to me! I will indeed batch my edits next time.

Comment: You can flag and ask for the CW status to be removed. I have no idea what the prospects for success of that would be though as the application of CW status after many edits is by design and in this case the edits were all made in quite a short time period.

Comment: @MartinSmith I already flagged it, no answer yet.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer @TemplateRex? Same thing happened to me.

Comment: @ChrisRedford nope, deafening silence.

Comment: Ugh. I hate that system. Ironically, I think well-edited posts get more votes. Anyhow, I feel your pain.

Comment: Doesn't this way of scoring dissuade people from improving their answers?