# Upvote didn't increase my reputation (haven't hit the cap)

Tags: support, reputation

Here is a screenshot of my reputation for today:

[image]

I know about reputation cap, but as you see, it's not an issue. Why didn't I get reputation from this upvote?

Comment: [Your answer is a CW post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18160542/488657). This means you won't get reputation for upvotes. Given that this seems to be due to substantial self-edits, just flag your post and ask a moderator to undo it.

Comment: thank you guys, will know now

Comment: Or just delete it and post it again. You have gained no rep from it anyway and maybe who ever gave you the +1 originally will do so again.

Comment: so just delete it and post without undeleting?

Comment: @RomanPekar - I probably would. There is no guarantee that the moderators will agree to remove the CW status anyway and even if they do it might be a while before they get round to it. So in the meantime any votes you accrue you will not get rep for.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's poor advice. Just leave it in place Roman. CW status will be undone.

Comment: @Bart - There is no guarantee of that at all. See [for example this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188364/145673). The answer still has CW status so I presume it was declined. I've also requested CW status to be removed on an answer before and had it declined.

Comment: @MartinSmith Well, colour me surprised... You just received a "declined" message? No motivation?

Comment: @Bart - "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.". The situation was slightly different in that I supplied an answer to a question that the OP had made CW by editing the question too many times so my answer was automatically CW but in my view that should have strengthened the case for its removal.

Comment: @MartinSmith Hmm, in that case I'm not sure CW could have been undone for your answer. It would have had to be reversed for the entire question if I'm not mistaken. But still, for the other example you linked I'm somewhat surprised it wasn't reversed. Though I'm not sure what the flag was. I'm almost inclined to ask for clarification on the issue. Let's see what happens to this particular situation....

Comment: Ok @MartinSmith thanks, I'll go your way. My algorithm is still the fastest answer there (if i haven't missed some case), so there could be some upvotes and I don't want to miss it

Comment: @MartinSmith FYI, I've asked a question about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192784/what-criteria-are-taken-into-account-when-deciding-to-undo-community-wiki-status

Comment: @Bart - Thanks. Will keep an eye on it. Will be interested to see what criteria are taken into account. If the answer had existing upvotes before CW status had been applied then I can see why there would be an incentive to ask a moderator to do it but in this case that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159911/longest-equally-spaced-subsequence/18160542#18160542) became community wiki when you last edited it (revision 12). This happens automatically after either five authors editing a post, or one author editing a post ten times. The revision summary reads:

> added 174 characters in body; [made Community Wiki by Roman Pekar editing at least 10 times]

You hit the edit limit. If you'd like it unwikied, you can flag a moderator and, in most cases, they will unwiki it.

Unfortunately, even if they do, that ten reputation is lost.

Comment: thanks, will accept the answer in 10 minutes